# 503 Service Unavailable when passing periods in URL in PHP

Tags: php, url-encoding, http-status-code-503

I am working on a website where you can provide contact details and submit it to a PHP page. These contact details will be sent to an email address using the native PHP `mail()` function. However, everything seems fine and works with the following code:

```
<?php

$salutation = $_GET["salutation"];
$name = $_GET["name"];
$plan = $_GET["plan"];
$desc = $_GET["desc"];

$to = "example@email.com";
$subject = $desc;

$msg = "

<html>
<body>
    <p>Test body</p>
</body>
</html>

";

$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";

mail($to, $subject, $msg, $headers);

?>
```

When you submit the form, the end of the URL bar changes to:

```
page.php?salutation=dhr&name=Kees+van+Voorthuizen&plan=basic&desc=Test+Description
```

As I said, this works properly and no errors were thrown.
But when I add an `<input name="email" id="email" type="email">` to the contact details page inside the `<form>` tag and I submit the form using my own email address, the server returns an HTTP error 503. PHP code **using the email input field**:

```
<?php

$salutation = $_GET["salutation"];
$name = $_GET["name"];
$email = $_GET["email"];  // <--- The only thing that has changed
$plan = $_GET["plan"];
$desc = $_GET["desc"];

$to = "example@email.com";
$subject = $desc;

$msg = "

<html>
<body>
    <p>Test body</p>
</body>
</html>

";

$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";

mail($to, $subject, $msg, $headers);

?>
```

The URL now ends in:

```
page.php?salutation=dhr&name=Kees+van+Voorthuizen&email=my%40email.com&plan=basic&desc=Test+Description
```

I suspect that the error is being thrown when I include a period ('.') inside the email field. I've tried manually changing the URL bar using `my%40emailcom` instead of `my%40email.com` and *it worked*. Notice that I removed the period between `email` and `com`.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure it's a 503 and not 500?

Comment: @Devon Yes, I am sure of that. The page title in Google Chrome indicates '503 Service Unavailable'. Message: `The server is temporarily unable to service your request due to maintenance downtime or capacity problems. Please try again later.`

Comment: I would (a) http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php whatever goes in there (in the end there can be many other characters that need encoding) (b) use a class and no scripting like syntax (c) I would not use GET but POST in the form to submit

Comment: @edelwater Thank you for your answer! I will attempt to implement this.